# Rails 4: before_save callback not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, callback, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic `lookups` table with a child `ContractType` model. I have a `before_save` callback in the `ContractType` model that sets a `category`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
class Lookup < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :value, presence: true
  validates :category, presence: true
end

class ContractType < Lookup
  before_save { self.category = "contract_type" }
end
```

Then I open the `rails c`:

```
> c = ContractType.create(value: "test")
> c.errors.messages
=> { :category => ["can't be blank"] }
```

I don't get any errors, just a failed validation.  As far as I know, the syntax looks correct, it's just that the `before_save` callback doesn't seem to be working...

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 10):

I found the problem...validations take place BEFORE the `save`, so it always "failed" validation and stopped before the `before_save` callback took place.

The solution is to use a `before_validation` callback.

```
class ContractType < Lookup
  before_validation { self.category = "contract_type" }
end
```

My misunderstanding of the order of events.

Answer (score 0):

I know you found your solution, but think about your problem and solution logically. You are hard coding the category value. It means that the user cannot leave it blank. It will always be filled. So why have a validation for it in the first place? Just remove this:

```
validates :category, presence: true
```

In the before_save callback, you will know the value will be assigned. before_validation does have use cases. For example, a user enters a value for a currency attribute and you want to format the currency prior to validation. But in your case, before_validation is not needed.